# Is it acceptable to use document.getElementById() in React components?

Tags: reactjs

I'm wondering whether it is acceptable to use such vanilla js methods for dom manipulation inside react components. What happens if your senior dev sees that in a company? Do they kick you out?

Comment: More often than not, you should be using refs: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 1):

I think it's acceptable *if* the element you're referring to by `id` is not managed by React (e.g. some of your app is React, the rest is static/vanilla).  If the element is managed by React, it's better to use `ref`s and so on.